# phoneGap: getDevicePosition

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to write a function that returns an object representing the position of the device: 
I have tried:

```
  function getDevicePosition () {
    var positionObject;
    if (isDeviceReady) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            ;
            positionObject = position;
            console.log('location updated');
            console.log(positionObject.coords.longitude);//1. works
        }, function (err) {
            console.log('Failed to get device position' + err);
            return null;
        });

    } else {
        warnUser();
        return null;
    }
    console.log(positionObject.coords.longitude);//2. doesnt work as positionObject is null.
    return positionObject;
}
```

perhaps I should rephrase my question. Notice that I have added comments marking statement 1 and statement 2. If I initialized position object in statement 1. Why is it undefined in statement 2?

Comment: on what device are you trying?? have you turned ON device's GPS assistance.?

Comment: Thanks... I've changed the question to add the required info.Yes the device's gps is on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the `android` tag I'm presuming you're testing on an Android device.

If that's the case, you need to add the right permissions in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

**Specifially**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONTROL_LOCATION_UPDATES" />
```

**Read more [here](https://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/using-the-gps).**

Comment: this is not the case positionObject is defined at the line marked 1.

Comment: Sorry can you please explain what you mean? Also you have a redundant semi-colon on line 5 of your snipped.